# Has anyone used Genetify for A/B testing

Tags: analytics, a-b-testing, open-source

I'm working on a small project that will likely run on Wordpress, I always like to run some split testing to improve conversion rates for various goals. Typically if its a small site that I either don't have a budget for or want to keep it as inexpensive as possible I use Google Website Optimizer if I do have a budget I go with Visual Website Optimizer both are great and affordable, but for fun I was checking out alternatives and found Genetify which is an open source project and has some neat features. In searching around I don't see many people talking about it and wondered if anyone here has used it. If so what do you think about it?

Comment: This seems open-ended. So it may be more appropriate to make this a community wiki.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'm relatively new here and don't see a way to move it. Perhaps I need more rep for that?

Comment: Thanks for the info, when I edit there's no community wiki check box.

Comment: Nobody?  Even with the bounty???

Answer (score 2):

In the past, I've done limited A/B testing and just used a modulus operator on the page to split on a random number. Then I showed one or the other items, and tracked in the log file...

Not ideal I know.

I did see this though that may give you more info down the path you're looking for...

http://www.bradleyspencer.com/2009/genetify-a-free-open-source-alternative-to-google-website-optimizer-for-split-testing/

It mentions a comparison between google and genetify...

https://github.com/gregdingle/genetify/wiki/compare-with-gwo

HTH